# Create some child files on create entity event

Tags: cuba-platform

I have entity named `Products` (`name`, `description`), and then entity named `ProductPrices` (`Product`, `Rate`, `Price`), and entity Rates.

I need to get all the rates available when I create a product, and create the entries in `ProductPrices` for editing `prices`, and editing `prices` on the same screen (same grid) not using editor screen of `ProductPrices`.

On same Question, when I add a new `Rate`, I need to create all records in all available products.

How can I do this step in my test project ?

Comment: Could you attach a sketch of the desired screen layout?

Answer (score 1):

In the data model, I've marked the collection of `ProductPrice` in `Product` as `@Composition`. It means that product prices will be edited only as part of a product.

```java
public class Product extends StandardEntity {

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    protected String description;

    @OrderBy("orderNo")
    @Composition
    @OnDelete(DeletePolicy.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    protected List<ProductPrice> prices;
```

The `ProductPrice` entity has an invisible attribute `orderNo` for proper sorting in the table.

For automatic adding product prices when a new product is created, I implemented the `initNewItem()` method in the product editor:

```java
public class ProductEdit extends AbstractEditor<Product> {

    @Inject
    private Metadata metadata;
    @Inject
    private DataManager dataManager;

    @Override
    protected void initNewItem(Product item) {
        item.setPrices(new ArrayList<>());

        List<Rate> rates = dataManager.loadList(
                LoadContext.create(Rate.class).setQuery(
                        LoadContext.createQuery("select r from products$Rate r order by r.name")));

        int i = 0;
        for (Rate rate : rates) {
            ProductPrice productPrice = metadata.create(ProductPrice.class);
            productPrice.setProduct(item);
            productPrice.setRate(rate);
            productPrice.setPrice(BigDecimal.ZERO);
            productPrice.setOrderNo(i++);
            item.getPrices().add(productPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to edit prices inline, I've set `editable="true"` for table and its `price` column:

```xml
<table id="pricesTable"
       editable="true"
       height="200px"
       width="100%">
    <columns>
        <column id="rate"/>
        <column id="price"
                editable="true"/>
    </columns>
```

Your requirement of creating corresponding product prices for all products when a new `Rate` is added can be implemented by an entity listener:

```java
@Component("products_RateEntityListener")
public class RateEntityListener implements BeforeInsertEntityListener<Rate> {

    @Inject
    private Persistence persistence;
    @Inject
    private Metadata metadata;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeInsert(Rate entity) {
        TypedQuery<Product> query = persistence.getEntityManager().createQuery("select p from products$Product p", Product.class);
        List<Product> products = query.getResultList();
        for (Product product : products) {
            ProductPrice productPrice = metadata.create(ProductPrice.class);
            productPrice.setProduct(product);
            productPrice.setRate(entity);
            productPrice.setPrice(BigDecimal.ZERO);

            Integer maxOrder = product.getPrices().stream()
                    .map(ProductPrice::getOrderNo)
                    .max(Integer::compareTo)
                    .orElse(0);
            productPrice.setOrderNo(maxOrder + 1);

            persistence.getEntityManager().persist(productPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

The working sample project is available [here](http://files.haulmont.com/uploads/1979212104.products.zip).

Answer (score 0):

i've attached a Screenshot of my Screen. For me is OK. Problem is when i'm creating a new producto, we need to insert in their Prices all available Rates in Table Rates.

[Screen Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqSKg.png)

[Entity Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plKSc.png)

When i create a new RAte, i need to add in ProductPrices a value 0 for all existing products.

When i create a new Product i need to add in ProductPrices a value 0 for all available rates.

Answer (score 0):

Other Captures

[Entity ProductPrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Johi.png)

[Entity Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQE7D.png)